# How to print visual studio 2017 nuget project reference warnings

Tags: .net-core

Using Visual Studio 2017 Community. My .NetCoreApp 1.1 project has included 2 packages from nuget that are yielding the little yellow warning label. The packages are obviously not loading correctly and I would like to know why.

- I have looked in output
- I have looked in package manager console
- I have built and rebuilt the project

The packages in question are :

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets (1.0.1)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol (0.1.0)

Additionally, this is not an issue with my other .NetCore 1.1 project in the same solution.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets" Version="1.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Protocol" Version="0.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebSockets.Server" Version="0.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: what if you manually call `dotnet restore` for that project?

Comment: Still has issues. That said, even If I were to fix it I would still like to know how to read the warning messages.